# How to obtain IMEI via adb?

Tags: android, android-12

I'm trying to track devices, SIMs and airtime cards for test purposes.  I have multiple devices plugged into a computer and since the recent update to Android 12, I am not able to get the device IMEI. The IMEI is basically the device's FCC-required serial number and can be obtained from the UI with relative ease, but how can I obtain it via ADB or in some automated method on multiple devices from multiple carriers and OEMs?

Prior to Android 12 FEB patch, I would use `service call iphonesubinfo 1` or `service call iphonesubinfo 4`.  But unfortunately after the update I receive back `Result: Parcel(ffffffffc ffffffff 00000000 '................')` whereas before I would receive a parcel containing the IMEI for processing via script.

Is there a way to get IMEI on Android 12+?  I am trying to stay away from using an app.  This is a simple thing, from a privileged user (adb shell).  It seems like a basic necessity for tracking and logistics purposes.

Comment: Access to the IMEI has been greatly reduced, because its use in tracking is so powerful and that its malicious uses far outweigh its legit ones.  If you just need a unique key for the device, why not create and store a UUID on the phone?

Comment: Factory resets are performed on these devices.  While I would agree with the decision on removing IMEI from apps, I would say Android Debug Bridge should have some way to obtain this information.  Part of the primary utilization of ADB is to replace a human performing work on the device.  A human can access the IMEI via *#06#, so ADB should have an equivalent method to perform the same work.

Comment: Not every device supports that USSD code.  Those are all carrier and OEM specific.  Every device you have may support them, but that's FAR from universal

Comment: Every device from every OEM and Chipset I've seen supports those codes. That's about 200 different models from 7 OEMs in USA.

Comment: USSDs aren't supported by chipsets.  THe support depends on OEM and carrier.  And yes, there are many that don't support those specific codes.  USSD tends to be more tied to the carrier than anything else, since the main use of USSD was actually to more or less be webservices in the pre-data days.  Of course that doesn't have anything to do with your original question.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're talking about something else entirely.   This is the AOSP Phone info in the dialer.  This information is entirely controlled by the interface phone info.  From what I can see, reading the code in the last couple of days,  AOSP renamed the interface and didn't hook things back up properly.

Comment: And not every phone has the AOSP dialer.  You can't rely on a particular USSD code being universal.  I wouldn't really suggest using IMEI for logistics purposes, Google really does try to hide it.  Places I've worked generally print a barcode and glue it to the device,

Comment: You're not being helpful.  This is not the dialer per-sae it's the telephony package.  Yes. google hides it from apps.  But there is no valid use case to hide it from adb shell.

Comment: The valid use case is they want to hide it.  It isn't a bug that its no longer there.  You may *wish* it was, that's not going to make it appear.  Do not rely on the IMEI, they go to great lengths to make it not publicly available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command works to obtain IMEI.  It works by pressing the dialer key, then typing `*#06#`, then parsing the text on screen to find the IMEI Label and the next element which contains the actual IMEI.  Finally it parses that element by removing all before `text="` and all after `"`.

```
adb shell "imei=$(input keyevent KEYCODE_CALL;sleep 1;input text '*#06#'; uiautomator dump --compressed /dev/stdout|sed s/\>\<\/\\n/g|grep -A1 IMEI|tail -n1|sed -e 's/.*text=\"//' -e 's/\".*//'); echo ${imei}"
```

to get just the 16-digit IMEI without checksum, replace the final echo statement with `echo ${imei:0:16}`

Comment: If this doesn't work, open the dialer app, and focus the text area for the phone number.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good solution for Samsung One UI

First, run the About menu

```
adb shell am start -a com.android.settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS
```

Then dump the UI

```
adb shell uiautomator dump
```

View the dump file

```
adb shell cat /sdcard/window_dump.xml
```

The IMEI1 in the **<node index="12"** and IMEI 2 in **<node index="13"**

Answer (score 0):

I have created a script to extract device information (including IMEI) which theoretically works on all Android versions.

For those interested: https://github.com/micro5k/microg-unofficial-installer/blob/main/utils/device-info.sh

Comment: iPhoneSubInfo has been broken for IMEI since Android 11

Comment: You can get the serial number via Adb Devices.

Comment: @AdamOutler Are you saying this on a bias or have you actually tried the script?
I have tried on Android 4.4, 7, 13 and 14 and it worked perfectly (without root).

Comment: In addition my script also get the real serial number printed on the package (that in many cases, especially Samsung and Lenovo, isn't the same you get from adb devices).